# How can I findAll records which has ID in array of objects?

Tags: javascript, orm, graphql, sequelize.js

If I'm using Op.eq:

```
   where: {
        id: {
          [op.eq]: 5,
        },
      },
```

I'm getting list of chats of user with ID-5. But I don't see other participants of chat in users field

```
…
    “name”: “x”
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 5,
      }
    ]
  }
…
```

If I'm using findAll without operators, I'll get:

```
…
    “name”: “x”
    "users": [
      {
        "id": 5,
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
      }
    ]
  }
…
```

So, how can I get list of records where there is some ID in array of objects

When I use [Op.in] operator I lose other participants in array

Comment: please share some more code & describe what you want in your output .

Answer (score 1):

You can use or operator for this.

```
YourModel.findAll({
  where: {
    [Op.or]: [
        {id: 5},
        {id: 2}
    ] // You can add all your array items here in this format dynamically.
  }
});
```